# Python - Wrong indentation adding new element to imported XML with ElementTree.SubElement

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm trying to read existing XML, add new sub element and save it as new file by doing:

```
updated_file_tree = ET.parse(path_to_file)
updated_file_root = updated_file_tree.getroot()
parent_entries = updated_file_root.find("Parents")
for i in parent_entries:
    ET.SubElement(i, 'new_added_tag', value = "true")
updated_file_tree.write(path_to_new_file)
```

Expected result:

```
    <Parents>
        <Parent>
            <A value="value_a" />
            <B value="value_b" />
            <C value="value_c" />
            <new_added_tag value="true" />
        </Parent>
    </Parents>
```

Actual result:

```
    <Parents>
        <Parent>
            <A value="value_a" />
            <B value="value_b" />
            <C value="value_c" />
        <new_added_tag value="true" /></Parent>
    </Parents>
```

The problem, that new XML file has wrong indentation, and "new_added_tag" is not displayed as previous elements (A, B, C). XML is valid, but the question, how I can make it look exactly the same.